# Add unique id to rows in batches in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe in which I need to add new column with unique id in row batches.
For eg. I need to generate and assign unique id to first set of 100 rows and then so on for each batch of 100.

How can I get this done efficiently ?

Comment: Could you share the schema of your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

i hope i did understand well your question.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

df = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

# This creates a new column 'batch_id' which assigns the same id for each batch of 100 rows
df = df.withColumn("batch_id", (df["id"] / 100).cast("integer"))
```

monotonically_increasing_id() will create a unique id for each row.

Comment: This is incorrect. I tested your code and it is not creating a unique batch ID with batch size 100. The reason is that just using `monotonically_increasing_id()` won't suffice here as they are not consecutive. So, you'll have to introduce row numbers over this monotonically increasing ID as I have done in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78243996/9428810).

Answer (score 0):

<s>As you have not shared the schema of your dataframe, I am assuming your df has an "id" column. You can update it accordingly to any other column as per your requirement.</s>

You can simply apply the [`row_number()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.row_number.html) window function as follows to get the desired result:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, monotonically_increasing_id

# 100 in the denominator is the batch size
df = df.withColumn(
    "unique_batch_id",
    ((row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())) - 1) / 100)
    .cast("integer")
)
```

**Update 1**: As per your reply - you don't have an "id" like column so I have added a [`monotonically_increasing_id()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id.html) to make the above code work properly and fulfil your requirement.

**Update 2**: So, as per the comments, you need `uuid` and not integers as the batch ID - therefore I came up with the following workaround - extending the previous code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, col, monotonically_increasing_id, udf
import hashlib
import uuid

df = df.withColumn(
    "batch_id",
    ((row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())) - 1) / 100)
    .cast("integer").cast("string")
)

def generate_uuid(batch_id):
    return str(uuid.UUID(bytes=hashlib.md5(batch_id.encode()).digest()))

uuid_udf = udf(generate_uuid)

df = df.withColumn("uuid", uuid_udf(df["batch_id"])).drop("batch_id")
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas for replying. But In my dataframe i don't have any Id column. I have to add new column with unique id for each 100 rows.

Comment: Thanks @Vikas but I need to add str(uuid.uuid4()) to the batches not just an integer. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: @SurajPandey So, instead of a unique integer per batch - do you need a `uuid`? If I am understanding it correctly - you want the first 100 rows (1s batch) to have the same uuid and then the next 100 rows (uuid) to have a new uuid and so on right? Also, could you kindly clarify all your known requirements at once so the question is clear? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Vikas yes your understanding is correct. And that's the only requirement I have.

Comment: @SurajPandey I have updated the code - check update 2 - I have used uuid and hashlib to get the desired result - please let me know if this works.